# How to output an instance variable in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

For some reason I cant' find this in the documentation, but I'd like to do something like:

```
%span(class="widget_#{@widget.number}")@widget_number
```

So that the @widget_number variable is output to HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%span{:class => "widget_#{@widget.number}"}= @widget_number
```